# Update combobox in Add-in menu with new value

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint

I have put together a PowerPoint add-in that helps with updating some document properties. The "updating" of the properties works find with the callback routine I have in place for the combo box in the addin menu. But I also need to make sure that the combobox in the menu actually has the correct value when a new presentation is opened. So I need to update the combobox in the "OnOpen" event of the file. My problem s that I cannot figure out how to reference the combobox in the Addin menu. I have tried all ways I can think of without finding the right way.

What I am looking for is something like;
Application.AddIns("MyAddIn").CommanbarControl("MyComboBox").Text = "TheValueToApply"

But this reference is obviously not correct (as all other things I have tried).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I managed to figure it out. The trick was to update the xml for the ribbon to callback reference for a separate macro that provides the initialization value of the combobox. So my xml line for the box in question now looks like:

It is the getText part that brings back the initial value.
Just in case anyone comes across the thread and is looking for the solution.